# Remote connection to PostgreSQL between Mac and Windows PC through router not working

Tags: networking, postgresql

I have 2 laptops: one is Mac that running PostgreSQL and another one that runs Windows 8.1. On my Windows box, I installed ODBC driver for PostgreSQL.

Next I modified the `postgresql.conf` and `pg_hba.conf` in order to allow remote connection from my Windows box to the DB. And I tried to configure the ODBC connection appropriately. Everything is done but when I hit the `Test` button in the ODBC setup dialog. At this time I received an error message saying:

> Could not connect to the server. Connection timed out. Is the server running on host and accepting TCP/IP connection on port 5432.

I am not sure what else should I do. I am connected to the network through the Comcast modem/router. Should I set the `Port Forwarding` or `Port Triggering` for 5432? Or there is something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all happening on the same local network, correct? Not via a router or some setup where the client is on the outside of the network LAN, right?

What happens if you do a port scan—using a tool like Nmap—from the PC to the Mac? And on the Mac, is the firewall running? Check under the system settings for “Security and Privacy.” On your Windows client machine the firewall *might* be a factor, but I am not as familiar with Windows networking to advise on that?

In general what you are describing sounds like a firewall related issue. Either a port access setting or something similar.